# Why am I not able to fetch the HTML content from Lotus Notes using JavaMail API?

Tags: java, html, jakarta-mail, lotus-notes, mime

I am using JavaMail version 1.5.6 to retrieve emails from a Lotus Notes IMAP account.

Though the mail renders the HTML content properly when seen in the mailbox, the only Mime type available on reading the mail header is `text/plain` and there's no `text/html` type.

The `format preference for incoming mail` on the mail server is set to `keep the senders' format`

Comment: Have you added the IMAP support design elements to the mail file that you are trying to access? I.e., 'load convert -e mail\yourmail.nsf'.  See https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/conf_howdominomodifiesmailfilestosupportimap_c.html and https://help.hcltechsw.com/domino/10.0.1/upgr_upgradingmailfileswiththemailconversionutility_t.html